# SQL Server - DB Design - Data Integrity - Enforce attribute value W/O trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

I am fairly new to SQL Server, so apologies if my question is dramatically dumb.

Assume the following business rules.

1. `User` can be a member of 0..* `Teams` and as such is called `Team_Member`
2. `Team_Member` cand hold 0..* `Roles` within the team
3. `Role_in_Team` can have 0..* `Deputies`

Snapshot of tables:

**Teams_Members**:

- id_team_member (PK - surrogate)
- team_name (FK - Teams)
- team_member (FK - Users)

**Teams_Members_Roles**:

- id_team_member (FK - Teams_Members)
- role (FK - Roles)
- deputy (FK - Users) or (FK - Teams_Members)`

Can you think of any way of enforcing a rule that a deputy is a member of the same team (in other words - that a person from a different team is not assigned as a deputy of a role within that team) other than via a trigger?

Comment: Whenever the only way to enforce referential integrity is via a trigger it should a big red flag that your model is less than ideal. This seems to be the case here. But you have at least a couple of other tables (Teams, Users) that you sort of elude to but is not listed. Can you provide a more clear idea of what you are trying to model here?

Comment: I'm wondering as well if the 'deputy' concept should be modeled differently- if it's actually another role (Role/RoleDeputy) or if it's an attribute of a role (role.isDeputy).  Is a 'deputy' like a backup of a non-deputy?  Is there a hierarchy of deputies (in priority sequence) under a role?  All you should need to do is extend the team/role pair by deputies to ensure the deputies are in the same team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the logical design. If you insist on integer PKs for all tables, you cold **add** them to each table, but still have to keep composite keys (UNIQUE) and reference them in foreign keys.

---

**|** User `USER_ID` exists.

```
User {USER_ID}
 KEY {USER_ID}
```

**|** Team `TEAM_ID` exists.

```
Team {TEAM_ID}
 KEY {TEAM_ID}
```

**|** Role `ROLE_ID` exists.

```
Role {ROLE_ID}
 KEY {ROLE_ID}
```

**|** User `USER_ID` is member of Team `TEAM_ID`.

*For each user, that user may be member of more than one team;
for each team, more than one user may be member of that team.*

*If a user is member of a team then that user must exist, and that team must exist.*

```
TeamMember {USER_ID, TEAM_ID}
       KEY {USER_ID, TEAM_ID}

FOREIGN KEY {USER_ID} REFERENCES User {USER_ID}
FOREIGN KEY {TEAM_ID} REFERENCES Team {TEAM_ID}
```

**|** User `USER_ID` holds role `ROLE_ID` in team `TEAM_ID`.

*For each user and team, that user can hold more than one role in that team.*

*For each user and role, that user may hold that role in more than one team.*

*For each role and team that role may be held by more than one user i that team.*

*If a user holds a role in a team then that user is member of that team.*

*If a user holds a role in a team then that role must exist.*

```
TeamMemberRole {USER_ID, TEAM_ID, ROLE_ID}
           KEY {USER_ID, TEAM_ID, ROLE_ID}

FOREIGN KEY {USER_ID, TEAM_ID} REFERENCES TeamMember {USER_ID, TEAM_ID}
FOREIGN KEY {ROLE_ID}          REFERENCES Role {ROLE_ID}
```

**|** User `PRIMARY_ID` holding role `ROLE_ID`, as primary user, in team `TEAM_ID` is assigned deputy `DEPUTY_ID` for that role.

*Each user holding a role, as primary user, in a team may be assigned more than one deputy for that role in that team.*

*Each member of a team may be assigned as deputy to more than one primary user for a role in that team.*

*If a user in a team is assigned a deputy for a role, then that user holds that role in that team.*

*If a deputy is assigned to a user holding a role in a team, then that deputy is a member of that team.*

*It is not possible that a user is deputy to himself.*

```
TeamDeputy {PRIMARY_ID, TEAM_ID, ROLE_ID, DEPUTY_ID}
       KEY {PRIMARY_ID, TEAM_ID, ROLE_ID, DEPUTY_ID}

FOREIGN KEY {PRIMARY_ID, TEAM_ID, ROLE_ID} REFERENCES TeamMemberRole {USER_ID, TEAM_ID, ROLE_ID}
FOREIGN KEY {DEPUTY_ID, TEAM_ID} REFERENCES TeamMember {USER_ID, TEAM_ID}

CHECK PRIMARY_ID <> DEPUTY_ID
```

---

[image: team_member_deputy]